# Effect of creating an Exclude Filter without selecting a view(s)

Tags: google-analytics

My client has setup a GAN account and an App Property for a mobile app we are developing for them.  They desire to see the GAN hits in Real-time during testing, but then during production they want to exclude analytic traffic originating from their IP.

Normally they move all their available "views" over to the "Selected Views" column when the app is in production, and their thought was, instead of deleting the filter all together in order to test the app from their IP, they'd just move all the views back to the "Available" views column to essentially "disable" the filter. (see image below)

Based on the fact that our hits aren't showing up on the GAN site from our IP when the filter is configured as per the image below, it seems to me the filter is thinking "Since you aren't applying me to a specific set of views, that means you want the me to apply to all of them"

Is that a correct assumption?  I'd try myself but I don't have edit access to their GAN account

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my suspicion was correct.  I had my client move one of the views into the "Selected Views", and sure enough traffic was let through for all the views in the "Available Views", but blocked for the one in the Selected Views.

I had him move the view back to the "Available Views", and all traffic was blocked from all views.

So the assumption is correct: an exclusion filter is applied to all views unless at least one has been moved into your "Selected Views", then the filter will only be applied to that view.

Answer (score 1):

You could create three views (profiles):

1. All Mobile App Data (unfiltered)
2. Dev (include only traffic from dev id)
3. Production (exclude traffic from dev id)

This is what we typically do for clients.