# How to exclude internal traffic from Google Analytics using IP ranges?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

We have recently moved our website from being hosted on campus to off campus. We had include/exclude filters in place and working but those needed to change when the website went live. I got the external IP ranges from our networking people and created regular expressions using [IP Range Regular Expression Builder](http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/ipregex).

I verified that the RegEx is capturing the IP addresses using [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/#javascript).

I followed the instructions on this [Google page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en) to add the include/exclude filters. Then I added those filters to the appropriate views. For example, in my **Internal Traffic** view, I added all of my **Include** filters that have the internal IP ranges.

I waited a couple of days to make sure I am getting the filters to work but no such luck.

Lastly, I added a test filter on a test view that just included my IP address and that worked as expected when I checked the **Real-Time** view.

**Additional Info:** The DNS is hosted on campus.

Comment: Did you move the view(s) you need to work with the Exclude filter to the Selected Views or did you leave it in the Available Views? If yes, try to revert them all to the Available Views. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21053325/3832970).

Comment: You say that you added "all of my include filters".... how many include filters did you add that are related to IP addresses?

Comment: I have 5 include filters for the different IP ranges.

Comment: @stribizhev I will check that once I get to work. Sounds promising. Thank you.

Comment: Would you be interested in a different approach to excluding internal traffic instead of using IP Addresses?

Comment: Sure! How do I do that?